# Worklight skins gives error JSON store missing

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 6.1.0 and also jquery-mobile-1.4.2. I have implemented worklight skins.
But when I compile the code and preview it for "android.tablet" skin it gives me below error :

```
wlclient init started worklight.js:4673
before: app init onSuccess worklight.js:4673
Uncaught Error: Failed to call WL.JSONStore.init because JSONStore is missing in the application. Add JSONStore to the application descriptor, rebuild and deploy it.
```

This error I don't get when I run the code for android or If I run it using "Open Worklight Console". How can I resolve this error.

Comment: Did you follow these steps to enable JSONStore? http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_enabling_jsonstore.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a demo project showing this error for your specific case with exact steps, because I have followed the below and I see no error...

1. Created a new Worklight project
2. Added a Hybrid application
3. Used the wizard to add jQuery Mobile
4. Added the Android environment
5. Added a skin "android.tablet"
6. In application-descriptor.xml's Design view > Optional Features > I selected "JSONStore"
7. In common\main.js I added the JSONStore exmample from: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_init.html?lang=en

   I added alerts to the success and failure conditions
8. I then previewed the *skin* by using this URL: `http://localhost:10080/test/apps/services/preview/test/android/1.0/android.tablet/index.html`

The end result was that I saw the success alert, meaning that while previewing the skin, the JSONStore initialized successfully.

You will need to greatly explain what are you doing there, and provide a demo project (via Dropbox), so it could be further debugged.

Comment: If I run the app in simulator it gives this error but in real android tablet device it works fine. I am also trying other workarounds if it works in simulator also.

Comment: Like I wrote. If you experience an error - provide a demo project, because I cannot recreate it. Either that, or better explain yourself (by providing FULL steps).